# Knockout jqAutocomplete: How do I select an Id and Name?

Tags: knockout.js

I am using the Knockout JqAutocomplete pluggin. When I select an item from autocomplete, I want to select an Id and a name for that selection.
I know the documentation for JqAutocomplete appears to explain it very well, but I try all the variations and I can't get it to work,

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>remote data</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input data-bind="jqAuto: { source: remoteHandler, value: remoteValue, inputProp: remoteTest, labelProp: 'test', valueProp: 'val', options: { delay: 250 } }" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(remoteValue)"></pre>
            <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(remoteTest)"></pre>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>



var ViewModel = function() {
    this.remoteValue = ko.observable();
   this.remoteTest = ko.observable();
    this.remoteHandler = function(term, callback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            callback([
                { test: term + "-1", val: 1 },
                { test: term + "-2", val: 2 },
                { test: term + "-3", val: 3 },
                { test: term + "-4", val: 4 },
                { test: term + "-5", val: 5 }
            ]);
        }, 500);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/arame3333/b0jqmmjt/1/

and https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-jqAutocomplete

I only want to display the text and not the Id. But in the underlying viewmodel I want both to be updated.

Comment: If you remove the `valueProp` options, the whole item is stored in `remoteValue`. To only display the `text` prop in the UI, use `with: remoteValue` and `text: text` binds. http://jsfiddle.net/vzbr76yg/

Comment: Thank you. I tried all kinds of variations but I did not think of that one. That is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dataValue` option.

> dataValue - If specified, this observable will be populated with the currently selected data item.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xommbn62/1/